# APNS-php fails to send to more than 1 recipient when using production certificate

Tags: push-notification, apple-push-notifications

We utilize [php-apns](http://code.google.com/p/php-apns/) to send push notifications to our iPhone app users.  This worked great when we were developing, however once the app was in the app store and I switched to the production certificate, I'm only able to send to a single recipient.  Any more than that and no one gets a push notification.

I've read elsewhere that others have experienced this problem.  The only "solution" I'm aware of is to open & close a fresh connection to APNS for every push notification, but I'm not doing that.  That's not a good solution.

Anyone have any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the answer!

It appears to be an issue with sending to the development device tokens.  Like most people, we have a database that stores the device tokens, and the earlier records were populated with our device tokens from testing.

As soon as I net out those device tokens from my list, all works!

I really hope someone finds this useful!